# API Calling another API using Falcon framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, falconframework

I have two apis written using Falcon. First API returns some JSON response. Second API uses First API to get its response. When I independently run First API, I get response but when I use second API, I get a read timeout exception when this second API uses First API call. Any idea ?

**localhost:port/firstapi/{123}** - Works fine independently.

when **loaclhost:port/secondapi** uses **localhost:port/firstapi/{123}**. I get read time out at **localhost:port/firstapi/{123}**

PS : The two routes are registered in firstapi.py FirstAPIResource class.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are facing this issue because you are using (running) single instance (Worker).

When you try to call First API from Second API, falcon not able to serve First API as second API is already executing.

So if this is your requirement then try to use (run) multiple instance (Workers).

If you already using Gunicorn with Falcon then try following command:

i.e. Run Gunicorn with 3 workers

> gunicorn --workers 3 -b localhost:5000 main:app

And if you are not using Gunicorn then for more information follow [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-falcon-web-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04) and [this one](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/).

Let me know if you need any further help.

Also as mention in comment, if you are using Windows system then use [waitress](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/) instead of Gunicorn.

This will run waitress on port 8000 on all available IP addresses, both IPv4 and IPv6.

```
from waitress import serve
serve(wsgiapp, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

Also if you want to use additional parameter like no of thread you can refer [this URL](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/arguments.html)

Comment: How can I make use of multiple instances of worker processes at this line of code `httpd=simple_server.make_server('127.0.0.1', 8000, app)`. By the way, windows users use `waitress-serve ` instead of `gunicorn`